# Loopback app crash when I try to filter a non existent field

Tags: mongodb, rest, loopbackjs

```javascript
F:\apps\WPB\back\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:123
    process.nextTick(function() { throw err; });
                                  ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined
    at keyToString (F:\apps\WPB\back\node_modules\loopback-datasource-juggler\lib\include_utils.js:69:47)
    at Object.set (F:\apps\WPB\back\node_modules\loopback-datasource-juggler\lib\include_utils.js:75:13)
    at Object.buildOneToOneIdentityMapWithOrigKeys (F:\apps\WPB\back\node_modules\loopback-datasource-juggler\lib\include_utils.js:26:11)
    at includeHasManySimple (F:\apps\WPB\back\node_modules\loopback-datasource-juggler\lib\include.js:594:36)
    at processIncludeItem (F:\apps\WPB\back\node_modules\loopback-datasource-juggler\lib\include.js:366:16)
    at F:\apps\WPB\back\node_modules\loopback-datasource-juggler\lib\include.js:184:5
    at F:\apps\WPB\back\node_modules\loopback-datasource-juggler\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:3025:16
    at eachOfArrayLike (F:\apps\WPB\back\node_modules\loopback-datasource-juggler\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:940:9)
    at eachOf (F:\apps\WPB\back\node_modules\loopback-datasource-juggler\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:990:5)
    at Object.eachLimit (F:\apps\WPB\back\node_modules\loopback-datasource-juggler\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:3089:3)
    at Function.Inclusion.include (F:\apps\WPB\back\node_modules\loopback-datasource-juggler\lib\include.js:183:9)
    at F:\apps\WPB\back\node_modules\loopback-connector-mongodb\lib\mongodb.js:908:35
    at handleCallback (F:\apps\WPB\back\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:120:56)
    at F:\apps\WPB\back\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cursor.js:860:16
    at handleCallback (F:\apps\WPB\back\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\cursor.js:171:5)
    at setCursorDeadAndNotified (F:\apps\WPB\back\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\cursor.js:505:3)
```

I am using the loopback REST API with the a GET method `/users/{id}`

Parameters:
id: `me` (is the same that the id of my accessToken)
filter: `{"include":{"relation":"providers","scope":{"where":{"provider":"steam"},"fields":"providerId"}},"fields":"anythingThatDoesNotExist"}`

This is the query URL: `mydomain.com/users/me?filter=%7B%22include%22%3A%7B%22relation%22%3A%22providers%22%2C%22scope%22%3A%7B%22where%22%3A%7B%22provider%22%3A%22steam%22%7D%2C%22fields%22%3A%22providerId%22%7D%7D%2C%22fields%22%3A%22anythingThatDoesNotExist%22%7D&access_token=EFlnLANLgX9Uz6ilPKWa4sN73rKeE70oUean5hu3Zqkodp24oGN6BNyMSBwJLH3j`

The endpoints are free for anyone to use. And if any user makes a bad query my server should not die.

I would appreciate your help guys :(